# Large amount of JSON requests with many http requests, best way to manage this?

Tags: php, mysql, json, http, server

I am working on a project where there will be many users each with a specific key. This key will be used to request data through http and get some JSON data. the problem is that i am unable to send one request to get all of the updated data. i am only able to make one request per person per request.

I thought about using a cron job, but even so with a large amount of users i am looking at potentially thousands of requests running at the same time.

another idea was to have it only update when a user logged in, and once logged in updated on intervals, and stopped when logged out.

the issue here is that if there are alot of users logged in, it again will create a large number of requests.

My other idea is to use cloud computing to distribute the requests. the downside is that the main server (holding the json data) will be getting a heavy load because of this, primarily because of my scripts. (trying to avoid this)

what is the best approach here?

**example**:
**Main Server**: *holds* all dynamic data.
**Web Server**: *wants* all dynamic data.
1,000 users on webserver = 1,000 requests to mainserver 

The webserver sends a request via http to mainserver.
mainserver replies with data formatted in JSON.

restrictions: 1 query per request (only data for a single user) 
i need 1,000 querys to get data for all users.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Could you illustrate it with an example that points out where the pain points are?

Comment: updated with an example at the bottom :)

Comment: Assuming that by "mainserver" you mean database server, would a persistent database connection be of benefit?

Comment: I should probably note this is an API on the mainserver. and one i don't have sql access to, or any other access except http.

Comment: First of all, are you sure 1000 requests is bad? If yes, then since we can't tweak main server, the only way is to think about your business logic and find out how to reduce the number of simultaneously requests. We can't help you until you provide more information about your application.

Comment: only using 1,000 as a random example. fix to 10,000 potential. I just want to avoid problems in the future so that it won't ever be an issue. Here is an example of an API request https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/pvp/stats?access_token=FC1DE14D-3371-EC4F-BCC6-F35B400AB48ACDFEAAD6-6926-42FD-92FD-3764F0707819 my script takes this data and then splits it into an array. from there it is displayed in their user profile for everyone to see. (the application is a forum) obviously loading a request for every single page load is a bad idea, so i'm trying to get around this.

Comment: I don't see limits for Guild Wars API v2. They should return players data from cache, so it is unlikely they will notice your 10000 requests. 
On other hand, you can define separate script which takes keys from queue (500 requests for example per second), send requests and update user data. This way you can control how many requests you send to API. Read about implementation of queues in relevant programming language or using relevant database or if you really have high-load use something like RabbitMQ